# Filtering with a callable functions for multiples columns in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

how can you avoid using anonymous functions for filtering with conditions on multiples fields in Julia and use callable functions to gain some performance?.

```
using DataFrames
df=DataFrame( a=rand(["cat","dog","tiger","parrot","elephant","mouse"],100000),
             r=rand(vcat(1:6),100000)
             )

##this is OK:
subset(df,  :r => r->r.>4) #using anonymous function 

##this is faster 
subset(df,  :r => ByRow(>(4)) #somehow is vectorized, this is the gain I guess!

##with multiples field: (animal could be dog or r higher than 4) 
subset(df,[:a,:r]=>ByRow((a,r) -> .|((a=="dog") ,(r>4)))) 
#fast, but could be faster without anonymous part "(a,r) ->"? 

##so wondering: 

subset(df,[:a,:r]=> ##callable function for the condition above
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`subset` takes multiple criteria as additional arguments, so I think what you're after is:

```
subset(df, :a => ByRow(==("dog")), :r => ByRow(>(4)))
```

I see about a 10% speedup from this, so it's not a game changer performance-wise:

```
julia> @btime subset($df, :a => ByRow(==("dog")), :r => ByRow(>(4)));
  677.500 μs (296 allocations: 358.28 KiB)

julia> @btime subset($df, [:a, :r] => ((a, r) -> r .> 4 .&& a .== "dog"));
  607.200 μs (215 allocations: 174.95 KiB)
```

Maybe consider a simple view with standard indexing?

```
julia> @btime @view $df[$df.r .> 4 .&& $df.a .== "dog", :];
  476.300 μs (14 allocations: 60.67 KiB)
```

Or `filter` which works elementwise anyway:

```
julia> @btime filter([:r, :a] => (r, a) -> r > 4 && a == "dog", $df)
  502.000 μs (27 allocations: 149.00 KiB)
```

In general a good reference for row opeations on `DataFrame` objects is the "Rows" section of Bogumil Kaminski's excellent (and always up-to-date!) tutorial Jupyter notebooks:

https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/06_rows.ipynb

Comment: Thank you. You are using implicity an “and” condition . How would you apply an « or «  condition in multiple criteria  of subset?

Comment: I don't think you are meant to, from the docstring of `subset`: `Return a copy of data frame df or parent of gdf containing only rows for which all values produced by transformation(s) args for a given row are true. All transformations must produce vectors containing true or false`. Why not just use the anonymous function (which is almost the same speed) or one of the faster alternatives if you mostly care about speed?

Comment: Yes, I got you. I just tried to create a function first and the result are almost the same. the improve were minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Between the anonymous function and a defined function with multiples field the gain were minimal or no gain. But It is important to wrap it with ByRow, since using broadcasting with anonymous function would have some losses.

using the function filter was the best with the callable function. Less allocation and time.

```
using BenchmarkTools 

#Scenario 1
@btime subset($df,[:a,:r]=>ByRow((a,r) -> .|((a=="dog") ,(r>4)))) 

#scenario 2: with callable function

function myfilter(a::String,r::Int64)
 a=="dog" || r>4
end 

@btime subset($df,[:a,:r]=>ByRow(myfilter))


#scenario 3: using the function filter

@btime filter([:a,:r]=>myfilter,$df)
```